# How do replace process by an interruption in contiki?

Tags: uart, contiki

I try to make communication between laptop and a module which use contiki as an OS, the question is how to replace  a process by an interuption in contiki?

I find that very difficult to do. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just poll for the process from interrupt context or raise an event for the process from other process context.
See process.h file for more information on process related APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Contiki frequently uses the Bottom Half pattern to deal with interrupt/process data exchange.

Interrupt Service Routine will buffer a received data an then wake/pull a process to process it.

I.e:

```
/* This is a ISR */
void uart0_rx_isr(void) __interrupt(URX0_VECTOR)
{
  /* read the UART peripheral */
  char c = ...;

  /* handle it to a process */
  process_post(&example_process,
                PROCESS_EVENT_NEW_BYTE, c);
}
```

More info here: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Processes